# Response code: 500 in apache Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

When i run load test of Website www.webgen.com on apache jmeter its return **Response code: 500** see attachment and when I insert www.google.com in Server Name or IP then Load test perform successfully. Any help will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks 
[see response code:500 in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg0q7.png)

Comment: error 500 comes from the server, so one of two options: 1 - your request is not right and server is rejecting it (or maybe you need authentication? cookies?); 2 - server has a bug. So nothing to do with JMeter really, it's a server behavior

Comment: Show screenshot of Request tab

Comment: Thanks, Kiril S for your response. I will communicate with Server administrator and forward your suggestions.